# How can I find a subsequence in a &[u8] slice?

Tags: rust

I have a `&[u8]` slice over a binary buffer. I need to parse it, but a lot of the methods that I would like to use (such as `str::find`) don't seem to be available on slices.

I've seen that I can covert both by buffer slice and my pattern to `str` by using `from_utf8_unchecked()` but that seems a little dangerous (and also really hacky).

How can I find a subsequence in this slice? I actually need the index of the pattern, not just a slice view of the parts, so I don't think `split` will work.

Comment: There is interest is expanding the concept of `Pattern` to arbitrary slices: [comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27721#issuecomment-185405392), [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/984).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation based on the [`windows`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) iterator.

```
fn find_subsequence(haystack: &[u8], needle: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    haystack.windows(needle.len()).position(|window| window == needle)
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(find_subsequence(b"qwertyuiop", b"tyu"), Some(4));
    assert_eq!(find_subsequence(b"qwertyuiop", b"asd"), None);
}
```

The `find_subsequence` function can also be made generic:

```
fn find_subsequence<T>(haystack: &[T], needle: &[T]) -> Option<usize>
    where for<'a> &'a [T]: PartialEq
{
    haystack.windows(needle.len()).position(|window| window == needle)
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I think I basically did it by hand with two nested for loops. The subarrays I'm looking for are all very small, so doing something more complex like KMP would be useless for my issues.

Comment: While this is a short and nice solution, please note that the algorithm runs in O(|haystack| * |needle|). This won't matter in most cases, but for more advanced and (asymptotically) faster algorithms, see [String searching algorithm (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Comment: This winds up being unacceptably slow. windows().position() is 100x slower than two nested loops.

Comment: @JasonN 100x sounds extreme. Are you sure you're compiling with optimizations?

Comment: @JasonN how did you do with two nested loops? This solution should compile into the same thing as one loop.

Comment: I would suggest adding an explicit check for `needle.is_empty()`, since `haystack.windows(0)` would panic, which is probably not the wanted behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the standard library contains a function for this. Some libcs have `memmem`, but at the moment the libc crate does not wrap this. You can use the [`twoway` crate](https://github.com/bluss/twoway) however. `rust-bio` implements some pattern matching algorithms, too. All of those should be faster than using `haystack.windows(..).position(..)`

Comment: I recommend [`memchr`](https://docs.rs/memchr/latest/memchr/index.html) crate.

Answer (score 3):

How about [Regex on bytes](https://docs.rs/regex/1/regex/bytes/)? That looks very powerful. See this [Rust playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=9461e5c8e9cbb429cb87d7c52c127009).

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::bytes::Regex;

fn main() {
    //see https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/bytes/

    let re = Regex::new(r"say [^,]*").unwrap();

    let text = b"say foo, say bar, say baz";

    // Extract all of the strings without the null terminator from each match.
    // The unwrap is OK here since a match requires the `cstr` capture to match.
    let cstrs: Vec<usize> =
        re.captures_iter(text)
          .map(|c| c.get(0).unwrap().start())
          .collect();

    assert_eq!(cstrs, vec![0, 9, 18]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the [`memmem` crate](https://docs.rs/memmem/0.1.1/memmem/) useful for this task:

```
use memmem::{Searcher, TwoWaySearcher};

let search = TwoWaySearcher::new("dog".as_bytes());
assert_eq!(
    search.search_in("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.".as_bytes()),
    Some(41)
);
```