# Is there a name for this for loop pattern and if so is there a better way to write it?

Tags: rust, semantics, idioms

Here is an example function with the pattern I am referring to:

```
fn check_sub_listiness<T: PartialEq>(big_list: &[T], small_list: &[T]) -> bool {
    for poss_sublist in big_list.windows(small_list.len()) {
        if poss_sublist == small_list {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}
```

This code takes a big list and a small list and returns whether the small list is a sublist of the big list. I wrote it as part of an Exercism exercise I was doing.
I find myself using this pattern alot, where I loop through some options, check for a condition, and return true if I find it or false if I make it to the end of the loop without finding what I was looking for. Is there a name for this? More importantly, is there a better more semantic way to write it (in Rust or any other language).

Comment: Does this find the largest matching sequence between two arrays?

Comment: It takes in two slices of generic type T and searches the large slice to see if it contains a the smaller slice as a sublist. The windows method returns an iterator over "sub slices" of a given size. So
```
for sub_slice in ['h','e','y'].windows(2) {
println!("{}",sub_slice);
}
```
would print:
['h','e']
['e','y']

I think. I typed this directly into comments so I have no idea if that works

Comment: There's almost certainly a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Haha that's why we're all here tadman

Comment: Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: If you're looking for a good implementation then you may be interested in https://docs.rs/aho-corasick/0.7.15/aho_corasick/

Comment: I think this question is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043167/does-rust-contain-a-way-to-directly-check-whether-or-not-one-vector-is-a-substr

Comment: So it's not the String search that concerns me. Depending on the implementation on the overloaded ==, I think this is roughly O(n), which is good for a haystack/needle problem I think. Im really wondering if there is a shorthand or more semantic way of denoting the loop { if found thing { return true } } if never found return false logic structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating until success is like [`.find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) but if you're only interested in a `true`/`false` result you can use [`.any()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any), which does exactly what you're asking for.

> Tests if any element of the iterator matches a predicate.
>
> `any()` takes a closure that returns `true` or `false`. It applies this closure to each element of the iterator, and if any of them return `true`, then so does `any()`. If they all return `false`, it returns `false`.
>
> `any()` is short-circuiting; in other words, it will stop processing as soon as it finds a `true`, given that no matter what else happens, the result will also be `true`.
>
> An empty iterator returns false.

So your loop can be written like this:

```
fn check_sub_listiness<T: PartialEq>(big_list: &[T], small_list: &[T]) -> bool {
    big_list.windows(small_list.len()).any(|poss_sublist| {
        poss_sublist == small_list
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop you provided is an instance of [exhaustive search](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Exhaustive_search&redirect=no), I would probably call it that. Hence the call for a more efficient loop, but I'm also sceptical if that's possible here.
If the big list is sorted, you coud work with binary search.

Comment: The big list was not necessarily sorted! The context of the problem was to find a phrase within an essay I think, but this was a long time ago so it's hard to remember.