# Why can I not use a slice pattern to filter a Window iterator?

Tags: rust, closures

I have a vector of numbers and use the `windows(2)` method to create an iterator that gives me neighbouring pairs. For example, the vector `[1, 2, 3]` is transformed into `[1, 2], [2, 3]`. I want to use the `find` method to find a slice that fulfills a specific condition:

```
fn step(g: u64) -> Option<(u64, u64)> {
    let prime_list: Vec<u64> = vec![2, 3, 5, 7]; //For example
    if prime_list.len() < 2 {
        return None;
    }
    let res = prime_list.windows(2).find(|&&[a, b]| b - a == g)?;
    //...
    None
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in function argument: `&&[]` not covered
 --> src/lib.rs:6:43
  |
6 |     let res = prime_list.windows(2).find(|&&[a, b]| b - a == g)?;
  |                                           ^^^^^^^^ pattern `&&[]` not covered
```

I don't know what that error means: the list cannot have less than two elements, for example. Maybe the closure parameter is wrong? I tried to vary it but that didn't change anything. `a` and `b` are being properly detected as `u64` in my IDE too. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You, the programmer, know that each iterated value will have a length of 2, but **how do you know that**? You can only tell that from the prose documentation of the function:

> Returns an iterator over all contiguous windows of length size. The windows overlap. If the slice is shorter than size, the iterator returns no values.

Nowhere does the compiler know this information. The implementation of `Windows` only states that the iterated value will be a slice:

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Windows<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a [T];
}
```

I'd convert the slice into an array reference, discarding any slices that were the wrong length (which you know cannot happen):

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn step(g: u64) -> Option<(u64, u64)> {
    let prime_list: Vec<u64> = vec![2, 3, 5, 7]; // For example

    if prime_list.len() < 2 {
        return None;
    }

    let res = prime_list
        .windows(2)
        .flat_map(<&[u64; 2]>::try_from)
        .find(|&&[a, b]| b - a == g)?;
    //...
    None
}
```

See also:

- [How to convert a slice into an array reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129565/155423)
- [How can I find a subsequence in a &[u8] slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35901547/155423)
- [How do I imply the type of the value when there are no type parameters or ascriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41882151/155423)

Alternatively, you could use an iterator of integers and chunk it up.

See also:

- [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134874/155423)

At some point in the future, *const generics* might be stabilized and allow baking the array length into the function call and the return type.

See also:

- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)