# How do I chain operators over lists in rust? Looking for equivalent to kotlin code

Tags: kotlin, rust, chain

I have the following code in kotlin and I'm trying to find a rust equivalent, but don't understand the chaining mechanism in rust to convert.

```kotlin
val windowSize = 2
val result = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  .windowed(windowSize, 1) ; [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
  .map { it.sum() }        ; [  3,     5,     7,     9,     11]
  .windowed(2, 1)          ; [[3,5], [5,7], [7,9], [9,11] ]
  .count { it[0] < it[1] } ; 4

;; result = 4, as there are 4 sequences that have first number less than 2nd,
;; when considering a sliding window over the original data of 2 items at a time.
```

It just takes a list of integers, splits them into pairs (but the windowSize will be a function parameter), sums those groups, splits the sums into pairs again, and finds where each second element is bigger than the previous, so finding increasing values over moving windows.

I'm converting this to the rust equivalent, but struggling to understand how to chain operations together.

What I've got so far is:

```rust
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
input.windows(2)
    .map(|es| es.iter().sum())
    // what goes here to do the next windows(2) operation?
    .for_each(|x: u32| println!("{}", x));
```

I can "for_each" over the map to do things on the iteration, but I can't split it with another "windows()", or don't know the magic to make that possible. IntelliJ is showing me the return type from map is `impl Iterator<Item=?>`

Can anyone enlighten me please? I am an absolute beginner on rust, so this is undoubtedly to do with my understanding of the language as a whole.

Comment: advent of code too?

Comment: i was going to tag AOC, but yeah :) I'm trying to learn in rust, but the competition of leaderboards at work mean I'm doing it in my preferred language first, then trying to convert to rust.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`Itertools::tuple_windows()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134874/are-there-equivalents-to-slicechunks-windows-for-iterators-to-loop-over-pairs)

Comment: @Stargateur done. let me know if there's anything else that I can add. I'm really trying to grasp the difference in the way 2 languages work than the results though.

Answer (score 5):

The [Itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate provides a reasonably convenient way to do this with the [`tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) method.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; 

fn main() {
    let input = [1i32, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let output: usize = input
        .windows(2)
        .map(|es| es.iter().sum::<i32>())
        .tuple_windows()
        .filter(|(a, b)| a < b)
        .count();
    println!("{}", output);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ad1add3b743293e524495745e772bd6)

The standard library does not have a way to do this without collecting the iterator first, which requires two passes through the data.

Comment: this is much closer to the kotlin version I originally wrote, thankyou @Aiden4.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit convoluted to chain everything. You need to collect into a vec so you can access `windows` again. Then you can flat_map the windows to array references (taken from this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58291802)) to complete what you want to do:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = [1usize, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let res = input
        .windows(2)
        .map(|es| es.iter().sum::<usize>())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .windows(2)
        .flat_map(<[usize; 2]>::try_from)
        .filter(|[a, b]| a < b)
        .count();
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1dc382fe9055ad6998aefe302077da6)

---

Note: Nightly feature [`array_windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.array_windows) that use const generic allow to remove the `.flat_map(<&[usize; 2]>::try_from)` call

Comment: is this normal practice in rust? feels a little OTT. is there a more idiomatic way to do this type of combinations, or is this just a feature of windows()?

Comment: While this does work, it feels wrong. Better to not use iterators instead of collecting for nothing.

Comment: @MarkFisher, you can rely on itertools windows_tuple from the other answer. But I would say most probably your approach to the problem is not the best one.

Comment: @MarkFisher it may be better to do it this way than to use itertools, one should benchmark to be sure, but this could be unexpected faster.

Comment: @Stargateur nice add-up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @Aiden4's answer, the best solution is to use [`itertools::tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows). It is however possible using just the standard library and without collecting to an intermediate vector using [`Iterator::scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan):

```
fn main() {
    let input = [1i32, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let output: usize = input
        .windows(2)
        .map(|es| es.iter().sum())
        .scan(0, |prev, cur| {
            let res = (*prev, cur);
            *prev = cur;
            Some(res)
        })
        .skip(1)
        .filter(|(a, b)| a < b)
        .count();
    println!("{}", output);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74ca77fa2da353440b87ebb8f6602a04)

Comment: that's an interesting solution, if i read it correctly, you're creating a kind of pair in the iteration by scanning it as you go along, then skipping the first (presumably 0) element to get the first pair?

Comment: Exactly. The first element returned by `scan` will be the pair `(0, input[0]+input[1])` so I need to skip it, then subsequent elements have the form `(input[i]+input[i+1], input[i+1]+input[i+2])`

Answer (score 0):

Using std and stable only:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = [1i32, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let mut iter = input.windows(2).map(|es| es.iter().sum::<i32>());

    let n = if let Some(mut prev) = iter.next() {
        iter.map(|i| {
            let ret = (prev, i);
            prev = i;
            ret
        })
        .filter(|(a, b)| a < b)
        .count()
    } else {
        0
    };

    println!("{}", n);
}
```

This should be very fast.