# How to correctly use `peek()` in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, regex-lookarounds, peek

I am trying to do something simple. In a slice of `u8`, I want to find occurrence of two characters `"\r\n"`. However, I cannot convert that slice into `String` using `from_utf8` because parts of slice after `"\r\n"` may not be utf-8 and as far as possible I don't want to use `from_utf8_unchecked`. So I tried something like following.

```
fn find_crlf(text: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    let mut textiter = text.iter().peekable();

    for (idx, &elem) in textiter.enumerate() {
        if Some(&elem) == Some(&b'\r') {
            if textiter.peek() == Some(&&b'\n') {
                return Some(idx);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

And I get following compilation errors, understandably. However I am not too sure how to go about doing this. If it were a `str`, it was simply `.find("\r\n")`.

Compilation Error ->

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `textiter`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:16
  |
2 |     let mut textiter = text.iter().peekable();
  |         ------------ move occurs because `textiter` has type `std::iter::Peekable<std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 | 
4 |     for (idx, &elem) in textiter.enumerate() {
  |                         -------- value moved here
5 |         if Some(&elem) == Some(&b'\r') {
6 |             if textiter.peek() == Some(&&b'\n') {
  |                ^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

May be I am missing something really simple, but stuck on this for quite some time now.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901547/how-can-i-find-a-subsequence-in-a-u8-slice) about finding a sequence in a slice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Usually, the best way to write this sort of code is to not use `Peekable` at all. It's a tricky API to use because you often want to call `peek` when you are in the middle of iterating, which usually means you have already borrowed the iterator mutably so you can't borrow it again.

But, since you asked about `Peekable` specifically, you could rewrite your code to explicitly call `next` in a loop, which is often the only way to use `peek`:

```
fn find_crlf(text: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    let mut textiter = text.iter().enumerate().peekable();
    while let Some((idx, &elem)) = textiter.next() {
        if Some(&elem) == Some(&b'\r') {
            if let Some((_, &b'\n')) = textiter.peek() {
                return Some(idx);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Generally, a better method for look-ahead is to use `slice::windows` or `tuple_windows` from `itertools`.

Given that your input is a slice, you can use `slice::windows`:

```
fn find_crlf(text: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    for (idx, window) in text.windows(2).enumerate() {
        if window[0] == b'\r' && window[1] == b'\n' {
            return Some(idx);
        }
    }
    None
}
```

In general though, I prefer the syntax of the `itertools` method, because you can pattern match on the tuple which feels cleaner than indexing into a slice:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn find_crlf(text: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    for (idx, (&elem, &next)) in text.iter().tuple_windows().enumerate() {
        if elem == b'\r' && next == b'\n' {
            return Some(idx);
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Or, even better:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn find_crlf(text: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    text.iter()
        .tuple_windows()
        .position(|(elem, next)| elem == &b'\r' && next == &b'\n')
}
```